# Entity Framework Code First: shared primary key

Tags: mapping, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-4.1

i have a existing table with a primary key over 3 columns (1 varchar and 2 integer).
How can i tell the entity framework to use this "key".
Is it possible using the modelBuilder, attributes or is there another way ?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fluent api you must use anonymous type:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourType>()
            .HasKey(e => new 
                {
                    e.VarChar,
                    e.Int1,
                    e.Int2
                });
```

Other way is using data annotations:

```
public class YourType
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string VarChar { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Int1 { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Int2 { get; set; }
}
```

In both scenarios order of columns is important. Once you try to use `DbSet<YourType>.Find` you will have to supply keys in the same order. EF also uses order internally.